# Running CodedUI Test From Another Application

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm planning to run my coded UI test from another project (in same solution). I added a reference of the CUIT project to my winform app project. Also I added these references as well

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.CodeGeneration.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.dll
```

My code is something like this

```
Playback.Initialize();
TestProject.CodedUITest1 coded = new TestProject.CodedUITest1();
coded.CodedUITestMethod1();
Playback.Cleanup();
```

However, I get an exception on the `Playback.Initialize()` call.
this is the message...

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll"
```

Someone said that installing Test agent 2010/Test agent10 can solve this error.
I installed MS Visual studio Test Agent 2010, but same error happens.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. I found that the message of the inner exception is

```
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {27876903-E697-4406-BF49-1B8B92CB8735} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."
```

After digging around I found that I have a 32 bit third party dll which I'm running on my 64-bit machine. The conflict is 64 bit process trying to invoke 32 bit process in 64 bit machine.

The **solution** is to change the project properties to target to 'X86' machine instead of 'Any'.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the test the same way you do and it worked for me.

Below are the reference dlls I have added in my projects

[image]

Please make sure you have added all the dlls. In case you are not able to find the dlls, look for them in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies.

If this doesn't work please provide the details of inner exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added all of these references in my project. Anyway I found an answer to my problem and posted the answer. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I tried...but I must accept my own answer after 2 days :)